# count the nested list in the given list of different data types

Tags: python-3.11

Given a list l = [1,2,3,['albert','nick'],5,[7,5,4],'jordan']

when counting it says,

for j in i:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

here's the code,

count=0

for i in l:
for j in i:
if(j%2==0):
count=count+1
print(count)
print(l)

this code shows error

Answer (score 0):

Not all elements of the array l are iterable. You have elements which are of type int, string and list. You cannot iterate through int.
Thus, the line :  "for j in i" throws an error when i attains a value of 1 in its first iteration.

Instead make use of the isinstance() function with which you can check wether an object is of the specified type